# Group by a filter on elastic then get the total hits

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elastic index with elements that look something like this:

```
{
   "_index": "logstash",
   "_type": "logs",
   "_id": "AU2E2aXQESJWOe",
   "_score": 2.248888,
   "_source": {
     "@version": "1",
     "@timestamp": "2015-05-24T07:36:04.811Z",
     "timeApache": "22/May/2015:17:31:56 +0200",
     "client": "XX.XX.XX.XXX",
     "method": "GET",
     "Status": "200",
     "request": "/some/path/",
     "querystring": "?some=querystring",
     "referrer": "\"http://im.areferer.com/en/ref/24230/874802/\"",
     "agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Safari/537.36"
   }
}
```

The thing is that I'd like to group by the "client" field (it's an IP) and then do a count (total hits), but I'm new to elastic and it's beeing an impossible task for me... Could some one shred some light on how to do that?

Comment: Yes, I guess if you know exactly what you're looking for it's easier to get useful results in your search. I'll mark the question as solved and duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: For IP fields you may find useful [IPv4 range aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-iprange-aggregation.html). Please not that the field which contains IP should be of [IP type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ip-type.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that client field is a `not_analyzed` string field I would use [term aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) as follows:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "ips" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "client" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved it. I was using _aggregations_ the wrong way, thanks a lot.